# Edit SimpleXML node in a foreach loop

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to edit a node value while in a loop. I can edit nodes with unique names just fine.

```
 $gdNodes->orgName = 'test';
```

But when I'm in a loop, the value is not saved when I output my XML.

```
foreach($gdNodes->phoneNumber as $phone)
{
    $phone = '1234567';
}
```

Both are SimpleXMLElement class objects. I don't understand why it's not saving. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't save because `$phone` is a scalar copy of the original value.

You should be able to reach your goal like this:

```
foreach($gdNodes->phoneNumber as $key => $phone)
{
    $gdNodes->phoneNumber[$key] = '1234567';
}
```

Comment: $key outputs 'phoneNumber'. Looks like I'll have to do it with a for loop. Thank you.